# Launch WinForm application Aerosnaped Right Aligned

Tags: c#, winforms, aero-snap

This should be a simple question, but search-foo has failed me. My goal is to detect that I'm running under Aero (Vista or Windows 7) and have my application Aerosnap by default. (It turns out that a corporate application I wrote is run by pretty much everyone aerosnapped right, with their Outlook snapped left.)

The application is WinForms and I'm currently doing

```
Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Width / 2;
Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Height;
Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top;
Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left + 
       Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Width / 2;
```

in my forms's load event. This works great, except that if they use WindowKey+Arrow, it acts as if it was just a normally located form. This means WindowKey+Right does nothing on first press and WindowKey+Left snaps left. This isn't a major problem, but I would prefer if I could specify a window size and then snap the application to the Right so those keys act as they would with any other application.

I'm not sure this is possible, here are the things I did find:

- [Save and restore Aero Snap position on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368540/save-and-restore-aero-snap-position-on-windows-7)
- [Handling AeroSnap message in WndProc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321549/handling-aerosnap-message-in-wndproc)

These seem to indicate that there is no special AeroSnap message available. Anyone know otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why checking for version wouldn't get you most of the way.
How to determine the Windows version by using Visual C# 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283

This might get you the rest of the way. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/1a82ec8d-afc3-4eba-8189-6ee105aa6249

Comment: Figuring out if I'm running Aero doesn't seem to be a problem, the question really comes down to the if snap positioning can be implemented in code. At this point I have expanded the window a bit larger than snap positioning would normally do, so at least an WindowKey+Right does something visually.