# Docking a WPF window to left/right sides of the screen windows 7/8

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In both Window Forms and WPF there is this `.WindowState` which I can set to

`Minimized`,
`maximized` or `Normal`

I wonder if there is anything similar already implemented for docking the window to the left/right sides of the screen like with the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> / <kbd>-></kbd> keys for Windows 7/8?

I've googled and it seems people call Win32 APIs and implement this on their own

Am I supposed to write a custom docking code or is there a simple flag I can set somewhere like the `WindowState` ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368540/save-and-restore-aero-snap-position-on-windows-7

Comment: @TFD your manners are broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a flag that you can set.  Windows changes the rectangle of the window, and the WPF Window has no knowledge of what is happening except that the rectangle has changed.

It is quite simple to change the rectangle on your own. (Actually replacing the functionality of Windows is a bit more challenging.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace StackOverflowWPF
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         this.Top = 0;
         this.Left = 0;
         System.Drawing.Rectangle screenBounds = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
         this.Width = screenBounds.Width / 2;
         this.Height = screenBounds.Height;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Window maximized state is more than just different bounds.

Comment: Not from the point of view of the WPF window.  Windows tracks the rectangles on its own.  The WPF Window has no knowledge of what is happening except that the rectangle has changed.

Comment: I improved my answer a bit based on what @Banana said.